# HP ProLiant DL360 G4p compatibility with external SAS enclosure

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas, hp-smart-array

I have a ProLiant DL360 G4p and a StorageWorks MSA60.  The SmartArray controller currently in the DL360 is a SmartArray 6400.  I would like to upgrade it to a controller with external mini SAS so I can connect the DL360 and MSA60.

Q1: Is this possible?

Q2: Which card is compatible/recommended? Or is there an adapter to take Ultra320 SCSI to miniSAS

Comment: This is a valid question. The OP is trying to navigate  a confusing set of proprietary server hardware requirements. It's old gear, though, so it is best to step up to more modern equipment.

Comment: @Hennes Yes, because some add-in cards are only compatible with certain other hardware.  Especially when the HP compatibility matrix pdf on HP website is a broken link.  ewwhite, I appreciate the info. Thank you

Comment: @h3rrmiller I did not think of compatibility problems. Without those the first question looked (but was not) silly. I am glad someone answered it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using a controller compatible with external SAS and the [ProLiant DL380 G4p](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12099_na/12099_na.html). However, the default riser for that model of server is PCI-X only, severely limiting your options. The [Smart Array P600](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12247_na/12247_na.html) is the only PCI-X controller available with an external SAS connection that would work for your situation. The PCIe riser option (#354589-B21) would give you the ability to use something like a Smart Array P800 controller...

The Smart Array P600 controller would give you a *single* CX4 SAS connector. You'd need a `CX4 -> SFF-8088` cable to connect to the MSA60 enclosure.

[image]

But honestly, this is not worth it.

The G4p ProLiants were a temporary bridge between the legacy SCSI and the new SAS world in 2004. The equipment is too old and too limited to invest any effort in trying to piece a solution together. While it will work, the DL360 is constrained on RAM, so it would not make a good storage server. The P600 is first-generation SAS, so it runs at 3Gbps. SATA drives in the MSA60 would be limited to 1.5Gbps.

Also see: [HP ProLiant DL380 G4 SATA support?](https://serverfault.com/questions/399387/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-sata-support/399393#399393)

Comment: So would it be better to just grab a G5 off ebay?

Comment: Yes. And better performance, too. G6 is a better bet.