# Hp Proliant DL380 G4 Power on without Backplane

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, sata

I got an HP ProLiant DL380 G4 for free and want to use it with SATA HDDs as described here:
https://serverfault.com/a/516949/290693
But how can i power up the server without the SCSI backplane, because the power Switch connects to it

Answer (score 3):

*Don't do it. There's no reason to pursue trying to convert an 11 year-old server to SATA. There's absolutely no upside to it.*

The backplane is not required to power the server on, though.

Comment: The power switch connects to the backplane so without the Backplane i can't power it on

Comment: Are you not using another HP backplane to do this?

Comment: The backplane is expensive and rare on ebay & co because it's so old and holds only 2,5" HDDs

Comment: And this is why you should abandon the idea. This was not meant to be.

Comment: Not very helpful

Comment: There's a right way to do this... but at a certain point, it doesn't make sense to invest the time or effort into such old hardware.

Comment: @user290693 The very first line of the help pages we expect every new user to read before posting states "Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment" - ask yourself if you adhered to this.

Comment: Also, I [answered this question thoroughly](http://serverfault.com/a/399393/13325) in 2012. It didn't make sense to pursue then, and it definitely doesn't make sense now.