# CentOS 6.2 Server hangs

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, hp-proliant

I have a problem with Centos 6.2 server that is running on an HP Proliang DL380 G4 server where I run a Public FTP Service. The system runs for about a day and then it suddenly hangs, and I cant connect to it until its rebooted.

What logs should I check to analyze if the issue is Hardware or sofware related.

Answer (score 1):

You want to analyze the ProLiant IML logs, which are available with the installation of the HP ProLiant Support Pack. Since this is a DL380 G4, you can also see this information from the ILO interface on the system. CentOS 6 isn't tehnically supported, but it obviously installs. [Check the drivers here.](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3288132&lang=en&lang=en&cc=us&cc=us&ac.admitted=1340997286646.876444892.492883150)

Based on your symptoms, I'd suspect that the system board or RAM are the issues on this 7-8 year-old server.

Also see...

[HP Proliant DL380 G4 - Can this server still perform in 2011?](https://serverfault.com/questions/243439/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-can-this-server-still-perform-in-2011/243441#243441)