# ProLiant DL360 ASR

Tags: debian, hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I have several ASR events on my DL360 G4p without any reason.
There is nothing in the log file. I installed a remote syslog server. There I only see the rebooting messages. In the iLO nothing is logged about the ASR, only that one occurred.

I disabled ASR in the BIOS, but the ASR events continue.

Comment: I forgot to mention, installed is Proxmox VE 2.2 (Debian Squeeze).

Answer (score 4):

First: ASR == [Automatic Server Recovery](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01158873&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=428936). This is HP's heartbeat/watchdog timer that helps the system recover from OS or hardware-caused lockups. There typically won't be an OS-level logs. You'd need to view the server's Integrated Management Log (IML). You can see that from the ILO.

You're probably due for a system board replacement, given the age of the server. I suggest this based on having deployed *a lot* of those systems in 2004 and early 2005.

The [HP ProLiant G4p](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12166_div/12166_div.html) was a stop-gap and small improvement on the G4 systems. The system boards of the G3 and G4 server had a predictable failure pattern.

In your case, the ILO shouldn't report much, other than the system watchdog-initiated reboot, but given that you're running Debian, you can install the [HP Management Agents (for Debian)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=4091412&prodNameId=4091432&swEnvOID=4123&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-c45bd2c25e6849d19f98427649) on the server to obtain a detailed view of what particular component may be causing the issue.

Also see: [HP Proliant DL380 G4 - Can this server still perform in 2011?](https://serverfault.com/questions/243439/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-can-this-server-still-perform-in-2011/243441#243441)

Comment: agree with @ewhite This sounds like a hardware issue other actauly OS ASR.