# "Discovery failed" message trying to install hp ProLiant Support Pack 8.30 on DL380 G4

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant

I'm getting the exact screenshots shown [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?locale=en_US&objectID=c01720428), and followed the directions there despite the model difference.  The BIOS had a different serial number for some reason, but it was an alphanumeric string still.  We checked that it did persist after a restart.  However, this didn't fix the problem.

Some suggest to run a .cmd file in the psp directory to auto-update everything, but I don't want to do that, I want to do them one at a time.

How do I get PSP to successfully install?

Comment: Use a newer PSP.

Comment: I downloaded the one on the DL380 G4 support page.  Do newer ones support this model?

Comment: Yes. Newer versions support it. Download the PSP for a DL380 G6 or G7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're trying to install a very old [ProLiant Support Pack](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/psp/index.html?jumpid=servers/psp) on your system.

I'd just download a [**support pack**](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884083&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_c4a548846c6241a68d6744ff70%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for a more recent-ish HP DL380 G6 server. The DL380 G4 you're using is ~9 years-old. [That's ancient in computing terms.](https://serverfault.com/questions/243439/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-can-this-server-still-perform-in-2011)

Try it and report back!

Edit:

Good that it works! As for your firmware problem, I can tell you that for a G4 ProLiant, there aren't many firmware updates newer than 2006. Those were also dropped from the newer PSP. All you should be concerned with are: [BIOS (Jan. 2008)](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3288132&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_3c502ebf3d484b88bcbbd135ac%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), [RAID (2.84)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=426654&prodNameId=426655&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-5ce6254771904e8982335ff710) and [ILO (1.94)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=397989&prodNameId=397991&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-6011807da53845899bda5311ba).

Comment: According to http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884083&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_c4a548846c6241a68d6744ff70%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken support for the DL380 G4 was specifically removed in 8.60, after being toned down to "baseline" (whatever that means) in 8.50.  Would you recommend 8.40 or 8.50?

Comment: That's support for the OS and driver slipstreaming for SmartStart installations. The CCISS driver for the array controller is the same for systems up through the G5. The monitoring and such will continue to work.

Comment: Well, it made it past 'discovery failed', so far.

Comment: Having some other issues with some firmware updates not getting picked up for some reason, but that wasn't the question, so I accept.  :)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kev See my edit.