# What kind of memory for Hp Proliant dl380 g4

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

I am trying to figure out what kind of memory this Hp Proliant DL380 g4 needs.

I can see that it will take PC2-5300 ddr2 memory from this HP article http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?SearchText=311143-421.

What I can not figure out is if it needs PC2-5300r (registered) or PC2-5300F (Fully Buffered).

Does anyone know which of these it takes?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have many memory options for this model, with its *SIX* DIMM slots and 12GB max. I'd strongly urge you to move on to different hardware, because the G4 platform was released in 2004.

See: [HP Proliant DL380 G4 - Can this server still perform in 2011?](https://serverfault.com/questions/243439/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-can-this-server-still-perform-in-2011)

Use the [**HP ProLiant DL380 G4 Quickspecs**](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=north_america&type=html&docid=12028) to find real part numbers for components. The part numbers, **343055-B21**, **343056-B21** and **343057-B21** describe the DIMMs compatible with the server. That's what you should search on. This is registered RAM.

[image]