# HP ProLiant dl360 G4 with external backup

Tags: storage, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, tapedrive

We are running a HP Proliant DL360 G4 with external HP Storageworks Ultrium 960 tape drive attached at the moment. Unfortunately the tape drive failed over the weekend and we are looking to upgrade the backup system to get more capacity. We were looking in to HP LTO Ultrium 5(EH957B) or 4 and IBM System Storage TS2250 LTO 5 but it would require an SAS card/port/socket to connect and our server is lacking it.

Is there a solution to this or do we need to upgrade the server as well?
Are there any SCSI to SAS converters available?

I know that G4p can have a SAS card put in but will it work with G4?

***Update:***

So we've got the Ultrium 1760 now, but it fails to backup anything. Windows can see it, BExec can see it and the HP L&TT sees it. The only thing is that when it finally comes to backing up it fails. Also the Self Assessment Drive test fails in HP L&TT.

The Drive tape is connected to the DL360 through Smart Array Controller 6400.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an HP (or IBM) LTO-4 drive like the [HP Ultrium 1760 (#EH922B)](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10446316/mfg_partno/EH922B), which still has a SCSI interface. *It needs Ultra320 SCSI, just like your current drive*. This will double your capacity to 1.6TB and still have some R/W compatibility with your existing tapes.

---

In the short/long term, it makes sense to replace the DL360 G4 server. It's 10 years-old, has been eclipsed by 5 or 6 product lines. It's is probably unable to keep up with the tape drive's speeds (only has two U320 SCSI drive bays). But if you need a straight replacement, one of the LTO-4 drives is the best bet.

Please see: [HP Proliant DL380 G4 - Can this server still perform in 2011?](https://serverfault.com/questions/243439/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-can-this-server-still-perform-in-2011/243441#243441)

Comment: @eyeball What path do you think you'll take?