# HP Smart Array 6i upgrade firmware on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, firmware

How can I upgrade the firmware of my HP Array controller 6i? can I upgrade using hpacucli? or any other CLI utility?

The server that I want to upgrade is a HP Proliant DL360 G4 with Ubuntu Server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That server predates Ubuntu! [It's too old](https://serverfault.com/questions/243439/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-can-this-server-still-perform-in-2011/243441#243441) :)

But honestly, you'll need an old HP Firmware disk or a supported operating system to run firmware updates on that controller. [Here are the controller updates.](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=426649&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=54)

Remember, this server went end-of-life in 2004 or 2005, so it's a decade old. Firmware updates weren't as important back then, so you're probably not going to gain much from running updates.

---

The most "recent" update for that server and controller combination is from July 2008.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but is the server that we had available, another question... Can I use RHEL live CD and then use the cciss rpm (Those that are included on the HP Firmware DVD) files in order to upgrade the firmware? I know is a trick but maybe it can help me with the firmware upgrade.